# Logstash: Multiple plugins in logstash input

Tags: security, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm currently using logstash and vulnwhisperer ( to extract openvas reports in json to a directory). This integrating went well.

Right now i'm having problems with the configuration file in logstash. 
Initialy it only recieved inputs from the folder directory but i need to parse information that i can obtain by querying the elasticsearch. So **i'm trying to use two plugins in the logstash input of the configuration file.**

As you can see below, the logstash is not working properly, he keeps starting and shutting down due to an error in the configuration file.

Below you can see both the logstash status and logs. I'm new to logstash so a really appreciate the help. Thank you!

*The ip's where marked as "X" just for this purpose*

**Logstash configuration file:**

```
# Author: Austin Taylor and Justin Henderson
# Email: austin@hasecuritysolutions.com
# Last Update: 03/04/2018
# Version 0.3
# Description: Take in qualys web scan reports from vulnWhisperer and pumps into logstash

input {
  file {
    path => "/opt/VulnWhisperer/data/openvas/*.json"
    type => json
    codec => json
    start_position => "beginning"
    tags => [ "openvas_scan", "openvas" ]
  }
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9200" (http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9200') 
    index => "metricbeat-*"
    query => { "query": { "match": {"host.name" : "%{asset}" } } }
    size => 1
    docinfo => false
    sort => "sort": [ { "@timestamp": { "order": "desc"} } ]
  }
}

filter {
  if "openvas_scan" in [tags] {
    mutate {
      replace => [ "message", "%{message}" ]
      gsub => [
        "message", "\|\|\|", " ",
        "message", "\t\t", " ",
        "message", "    ", " ",
        "message", "   ", " ",
        "message", "  ", " ",
        "message", "nan", " ",
        "message",'\n',''
      ]
    }

    grok {
        match => { "path" => "openvas_scan_%{DATA:scan_id}_%{INT:last_updated}.json$" }
     tag_on_failure => []
    }

    mutate {
      add_field => { "risk_score" => "%{cvss}" }
    }

    if [risk] == "1" {
      mutate { add_field => { "risk_number" => 0 }}
      mutate { replace => { "risk" => "info" }}
    }
    if [risk] == "2" {
      mutate { add_field => { "risk_number" => 1 }}
      mutate { replace => { "risk" => "low" }}
    }
    if [risk] == "3" {
      mutate { add_field => { "risk_number" => 2 }}
      mutate { replace => { "risk" => "medium" }}
    }
    if [risk] == "4" {
      mutate { add_field => { "risk_number" => 3 }}
      mutate { replace => { "risk" => "high" }}
    }
    if [risk] == "5" {
      mutate { add_field => { "risk_number" => 4 }}
      mutate { replace => { "risk" => "critical" }}
    }

    mutate {
      remove_field => "message"
    }

    if [first_time_detected] {
      date {
        match => [ "first_time_detected", "dd MMM yyyy HH:mma 'GMT'ZZ", "dd MMM yyyy HH:mma 'GMT'" ]
        target => "first_time_detected"
      }
    }
    if [first_time_tested] {
      date {
        match => [ "first_time_tested", "dd MMM yyyy HH:mma 'GMT'ZZ", "dd MMM yyyy HH:mma 'GMT'" ]
        target => "first_time_tested"
      }
    }
    if [last_time_detected] {
      date {
        match => [ "last_time_detected", "dd MMM yyyy HH:mma 'GMT'ZZ", "dd MMM yyyy HH:mma 'GMT'" ]
        target => "last_time_detected"
      }
    }
    if [last_time_tested] {
      date {
        match => [ "last_time_tested", "dd MMM yyyy HH:mma 'GMT'ZZ", "dd MMM yyyy HH:mma 'GMT'" ]
        target => "last_time_tested"
      }
    }
    date {
      match => [ "last_updated", "UNIX" ]
      target => "@timestamp"
      remove_field => "last_updated"
    }
    mutate {
      convert => { "plugin_id" => "integer"}
      convert => { "id" => "integer"}
      convert => { "risk_number" => "integer"}
      convert => { "risk_score" => "float"}
      convert => { "total_times_detected" => "integer"}
      convert => { "cvss_temporal" => "float"}
      convert => { "cvss" => "float"}
    }
    if [risk_score] == 0 {
      mutate {
        add_field => { "risk_score_name" => "info" }
      }
    }
    if [risk_score] > 0 and [risk_score] < 3 {
      mutate {
        add_field => { "risk_score_name" => "low" }
      }
    }
    if [risk_score] >= 3 and [risk_score] < 6 {
      mutate {
        add_field => { "risk_score_name" => "medium" }
      }
    }
    if [risk_score] >=6 and [risk_score] < 9 {
      mutate {
        add_field => { "risk_score_name" => "high" }
      }
    }
    if [risk_score] >= 9 {
      mutate {
        add_field => { "risk_score_name" => "critical" }
      }
    }
    # Add your critical assets by subnet or by hostname. Comment this field out if you don't want to tag any, but the asset panel will break.
    if [asset] =~ "^10\.0\.100\." {
      mutate {
        add_tag => [ "critical_asset" ]
      }
    }
  }
}
output {
  if "openvas" in [tags] {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => [ "XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX" ]
      index => "logstash-vulnwhisperer-%{+YYYY.MM}"
    }
  }
}
```

**Service logstash status:**

```
root@logstash:/etc/logstash/conf.d# service logstash status
● logstash.service - logstash
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/logstash.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-11-23 12:17:29 WET; 9s ago
 Main PID: 7041 (java)
    Tasks: 17 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/logstash.service
           └─7041 /usr/bin/java -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.compile.invokedyna

Nov 23 12:17:29 logstash systemd[1]: logstash.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 23 12:17:29 logstash systemd[1]: Stopped logstash.
Nov 23 12:17:29 logstash systemd[1]: Started logstash.
```

**Logstash Log:**

```
[2018-11-23T16:16:57,156][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2018-11-23T16:17:27,133][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.4.3"}
[2018-11-23T16:17:28,380][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of #, {, \", ', } at line 31, column 43 (byte 643) after input {\n  file {\n    path => \"/opt/VulnWhisperer/data/openvas/*.json\"\n    type => json\n    codec => json\n    start_position => \"beginning\"\n    tags => [ \"openvas_scan\", \"openvas\" ]\n  }\n  elasticsearch {\n    hosts => \"http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9200\" ", :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:41:in `compile_imperative'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:49:in `compile_graph'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:11:in `block in compile_sources'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2486:in `map'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:10:in `compile_sources'", "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:149:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:22:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:90:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:38:in `execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:309:in `block in converge_state'"]}
[2018-11-23T16:17:28,801][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2018-11-23T16:17:58,602][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.4.3"}
[2018-11-23T16:17:59,808][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of #, {, \", ', } at line 31, column 43 (byte 643) after input {\n  file {\n    path => \"/opt/VulnWhisperer/data/openvas/*.json\"\n    type => json\n    codec => json\n    start_position => \"beginning\"\n    tags => [ \"openvas_scan\", \"openvas\" ]\n  }\n  elasticsearch {\n    hosts => \"http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX\" ", :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:41:in `compile_imperative'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:49:in `compile_graph'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:11:in `block in compile_sources'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2486:in `map'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:10:in `compile_sources'", "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:149:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:22:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:90:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:38:in `execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:309:in `block in converge_state'"]}
[2018-11-23T16:18:00,174][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

Comment: Why do you have a value in parenthesis on the `hosts` line in your `elasticsearch` input ?

Comment: In the example i found they where using it like that, but i'm not really sure about the elasticsearch input sintax or the way i'm using two plugins.

Comment: You need to remove that and only have `hosts => "http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9200"`, it's gonna work much better

Comment: I have made those changes and unfortunately i'm receiving the same error  in the status and logs

Comment: Can you share the new error you get, there's probably another issue somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Please change the below setting

```
elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost" 
    index => "metricbeat-*"
    query => '{ "query": { "match": {"host.name" : "%{asset}" } } }'
    size => 1
    docinfo => false
    #sort => "sort": [ { "@timestamp": { "order": "desc"} } ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Angel H's answer is correct except that it excludes `sort`. Here's a detailed explanation for why your logstash.conf was throwing errors.

1. `hosts => "http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9200" (http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9200')` --> this should be `hosts => "http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9200"` if you have a single host. For multiple hosts, use `hosts => ["http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9200","http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9200"]`
2. query ==> value. Here the value should be in quotes `'`. Thus, `query => '{ "query": { "match": {"host.name" : "%{asset}" } }, "sort": [ { "@timestamp": { "order": "desc"} } ] }'`
3. `sort` should be within the `query`.

Here's the modified version that works:

```
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9200","http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9200"]
    index => "metricbeat-*"
    query => '{ "query": { "match": {"host.name" : "%{asset}" } }, "sort": [ { "@timestamp": { "order": "desc"} } ] }'
    size => 1
    docinfo => false
    #sort => '"sort": [ { "@timestamp": { "order": "desc"} } ]'
  }
```

You can easily test your `logstash.conf` file using `--config.test_and_exit` option in logstash without actually running Logstash. This is like a dry run.

```
bin sandeep_kanabar$ ./logstash -f ../config/logstash.conf --config.test_and_exit
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
Sending Logstash's logs to /<logstash_dir>/logstash-5.5.1/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
Configuration OK
[2019-10-25T13:19:32,018][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Using config.test_and_exit mode. Config Validation Result: OK. Exiting Logstash
bin sandeep_kanabar$
```

You can use the same to help you detect errors as well. For e.g

```
bin sandeep_kanabar$ ./logstash -f ../config/logstash.conf --config.test_and_exit
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
Sending Logstash's logs to logstash-5.5.1/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2019-10-25T13:07:12,480][FATAL][logstash.runner          ] The given configuration is invalid. Reason: Expected one of #, {, ", ', } at line 16, column 43 (byte 462) after # Author: Austin Taylor and Justin Henderson
```

`Line 16` is the one with hosts